# Angular UI Router extras future states + sticky

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router-extras

I would like to implement states that are dynamic and preserve the state. I looked at angular UI router extras by **christopherthielen** and it is extremely promising. Can i basically implement futurestates and make it sticky?

Comment: Can  you elaborate on what you would like to accomplish?  What do you mean by "dynamic states" and "preserve the state"?  Future States is for lazy-loading states and Sticky States is for "activating" multiple states at once.

Comment: I get states from a service which I can register it using futurestateprovider. I would want to populate menu tabs with the states. Once i tab item has been clicked the state on the tab has to be preserved even when i leave and come back to it later. This i think could be achieved through sticky states. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: this is what is said about sticky states "Sticky States allows a tree of states to be long-lived, running concurrently alongside one or more other state trees. "

Comment: When you say "leave and come back", are you referring to leaving the page altogether? Or just referring to switching tabs/state in the running SPA?  Sticky states can retain the DOM for a sticky state as long as the user doesn't exit the app.

Comment: i meant switching tabs. let me elaborate. I am developing a portal kinda SPA. each portlet will be a angular module which will be lazy loaded. once loaded the modules will have to be sticky. Also each of these modules will have states with controllers and services which will be resolved dynamically

Comment: Yes, from what you describe it sounds like future states and sticky states can help you implement your use case.

Comment: which process queue are you referring to?  Might want to open an issue on github if it's broken with 1.3.15

Comment: I am able to download the modules and make the states sticky. Thanks for the suggestion.